# JMeter plugin Manager Custom Thread group throwing error message

Tags: java, jmeter

I am executing JMeter script from behind company firewall. I had initial issues loading the JMeter Plugin Manager, but I over came it with a line of code (jmeter -Jjpgc.repo.address=http://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/) added to the properties file, provide as a solution in a group thread. Currently, when I choose Custom Thread Group and click on apply changes, I am getting the following error in the logs. Any solution to this is really appreciated.

```
2022-09-16 12:06:50,587 INFO o.j.r.JARSourceHTTP: Downloading: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
2022-09-16 12:06:50,677 ERROR o.j.r.PluginManager: Failed to download json-lib
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:478) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:456) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:199) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1382) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1295) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:416) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:388) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:570) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:554) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:415) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.execute(JARSourceHTTP.java:499) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getJAR(JARSourceHTTP.java:389) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.applyChanges(PluginManager.java:167) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerDialog$4.run(PluginManagerDialog.java:212) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar:?]
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638) ~[?:?]
    ... 25 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638) ~[?:?]
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you're trying to access:

```
http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
```

is being translated to this one:

```
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar

    ^ - ka-boom
```

It looks like you're being a [corporate proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) and your employer is monitoring your [HTTPS traffic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) via [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) certificate

Java detects inconsistency in the certificate chain and doesn't allow JMeter to make HTTPS request having this MITM certificate.

The solution is:

1. Obtain the certificate (you can get it using even your browser) (it's better to fetch everything from the root, including intermediate CAs and ending up with client certificates if any
2. Put the certificates into [Java Truststore](https://www.baeldung.com/java-keystore-truststore-difference)
3. Make JMeter aware of this Truststore by setting the following [system properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization):

   ```
   javax.net.ssl.trustStore
   javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
   ```

More information: [PKIX path building failed: SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed/)